# ng-repeat checkbox updation into database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

**Angular code**

```
$scope.delTodo=function() { 
   $http.post('delete.php',{
      stus:$scope.delstatus,
   }).then(function(data,status,headers,config) {
   });
};
```

**Html code**

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todocontent track by $index">
   <p class="cls-{{todo.inc_id}}">{{todo.todoName}}</p>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.delstatus" ng-click="delTodo()" ng-true-value="'{{todo.inc_id}}'" ng-false-value="'{{todo.inc_id}}'"  />
</li>
```

I want to update the database if checkbox is checked or unchecked and also when the checkbox is checked the css of specified text is changed automatically. checkboxes are in `ng-repeat` loop.

**Problem** - If the `ng-model` of checkbox is same then all the checkbox is checked .In this case the database updation work fine. But if I change the `ng-model` to correct the css part then updation of database not work.

Comment: Use `ng-change` and pass `todo` as argument to identify changed object..

Comment: everything working fine. now i just want to get the value 19 from {stus: {0: "19"}}